# Lost session variable after page reload

Tags: php, apache, vagrant

After login, I store session variable with logged username and redirect to `/dashboard/index.php`. Later I click in a menu link in my app that redirects to `/dashboard/kanboard/index.php` and `$_SESSION['user']` still here, but if I push F5 in browser (or in kanboard menu link) the method that check if `$_SESSION['user']` exist return false and redirect to login page. This strange behavior not happen in another pages like `/dashboard/index.php` where I can reload page without loose session variables. Apparently the files are quite similar.

**dashboard/index.php**

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$titulo = "Index";
include $path.'/dashboard/includes/userData.php';
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
   <?php
    include $path.'/dashboard/includes/header.php';
    ?>
  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
            <!-- sidebar menu -->
            <?php
            include $path.'/dashboard/includes/menu.php';
            include $path.'/dashboard/includes/top-bar.php';
            ?>
        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">

        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->

        <?php
            include $path.'/dashboard/includes/footer.php';
        ?>  
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var index = new Index(JSON.parse('<?php echo getJSONUser()?>'));
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**dashboard/kanboard/index.php**

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$migas = "../";
$titulo = "Resumen Imputaciones";
include $path . '/dashboard/includes/userData.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <?php
    include $path . '/dashboard/includes/header.php';
    ?>
    <!-- MONGO Chart-->
    <script src="/dashboard/vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="nav-md">

<!-- MODAL INFORMACION DETALLADA -->
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalinfo">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="mtitulo"></h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float: right;">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="mbody">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- FIN MODAL INFORMACION DETALLADA -->

<div class="container body">
    <div class="main_container">
        <!-- sidebar menu -->
        <?php
        include $path . '/dashboard/includes/menu.php';
        include $path . '/dashboard/includes/top-bar.php';
        ?>
        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">
            <div class="">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="x_panel form-panel">
                            <div class="x_title">
                                <h2>Resumen Imputaciones</h2>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="x_content">
                                <?php
                                if (isAdministrator()) {
                                    ?>
                                    <div id="tableImputaciones-loader" class="div-loader">
                                        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse spinner"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row" id="imputaciones">
                                        <div id="tablaImputacionesContainer"
                                             class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <table id="tableImputaciones" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                                                   style="width:100%">
                                                <thead id="tableImputacionesHead">
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody id="tableImputacionesBody">
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 more-results">
                                            <button type="button" title="Mostrar más"
                                                    class="btn btn-lg button-more-results" data-total-paginas="1"
                                                    data-tabla-ref="tableImputaciones"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"
                                                                                          aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="hidden" id="last-index"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        include $path . '/dashboard/includes/modals/showUrl.php';
        include $path . '/dashboard/includes/footer.php';
        ?>
        <!-- ECharts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/vendors/echarts/dist/echarts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/kanboard/js/utils.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/kanboard/js/index.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var index = new Index('<?php echo getUserName()?>');
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Method that check logged user**

```
function userIsAuth()
{
    // Si no hay una sesión iniciada, lo hacemos
    if (! isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    // If existe la variable de sesión "user" entonces es que un usuario ha iniciado sesión
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: These two pages worked fine until I moved the entire project to the dashboard folder. Before they were on www/html directly and includes had relative paths instead absolute.

**Edit 2**: Another change I did was create a Vagrant machine in Centos 7 with PHP 7.3.3 and move the entire project inside. Before this, the entire project works fine in another server with Debian, same version of Apache and PHP 7.3.1

Comment: where did you start session?

Comment: `if( session_id() === '') { session_start(); }` Try something like that but make sure it happens before you start pre-processing your HTML

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile ``userData.php`` script included in both pages have ``userIsAuth()`` method

Comment: And does it only “have” that method, or does the method actually get _called_? session_start should probably not be wrapped in this to begin with, a working session requires that you start the session in _all_ scripts along the whole path the user takes, and not just in some that might check authentication.

Comment: @04FS method get calles in every page